# Node.JS Connect counter

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was bored, so I created a connection counter(as displayed below) and every time a client connects to the server, it it logs the connection as if it was two different connections. Any idea on why this happens?

```
var http = require('http');

var count = 0;

http.createServer(function(request, response){
    count = count + 1;
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end('The server has been joined ' + count + ' times.');
    console.log('Server join: ' + count + '\n');
}).listen(8080);

console.log('Listening on port 8080');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check `req.url`, you'll see that the extra request is for `/favicon.ico`, which many browsers will make simultaneously if a favicon for the site is not already cached. Just check for it in your code and don't increase the counter for those requests.

Comment: As a beginner, can I ask how to check whether the request is `/favicon.ico` in node and don't increase the counter?

Comment: I don't know whether it is a good idea, add `if (req.url != "/") {
        return;
    }` did the trick.